# Change the symbology of a vector output layer that is returned from a processing tool?

Tags: qgis-plugins, symbology, qgis-processing, vector-layer, properties

I want to change the symbology of a Vector Output Layer that is Returned after running a Processing Tool. I am building a processing plugin. I am trying to make the effects reflect in the displayed output. I want the changes effected on the layer property after running each Processing Tool.

I have copied the relevant section of my code below:

```
def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, model_feedback):
# Use a multi-step feedback, so that individual child algorithm progress reports are adjusted for the
# overall progress through the model

feedback = QgsProcessingMultiStepFeedback(2, model_feedback)
results = {}
outputs = {}                                
            
# Fix Line Geometries               
alg_params = {'INPUT': parameters['VectorLineLayer'], 'OUTPUT': parameters['FixedLines']}
    
outputs['FixGeometries1'] = processing.run('native:fixgeometries', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True) #1

layer_A = QgsVectorLayer(outputs['CreateGrid']['OUTPUT'], 'layer_A')
renderer = layer_A.renderer()

symbol = QgsLineSymbol.createSimple({'line_color': '191,191,191,255', 'line_width': '0.20', 'line_style': 'dash'})
layer_A.renderer().setSymbol(symbol)
layer_A.triggerRepaint() # show the change
iface.layerTreeView().refreshLayerSymbology(layer_A.id()) # I want these changes to be effected in the output displayed.

feedback.setCurrentStep(1)
if feedback.isCanceled():
    return {}
    
# Using Field calculator to Add an ID
alg_params = {
    'FIELD_LENGTH': 10,
    'FIELD_NAME': 'ID',
    'FIELD_PRECISION': 0,
    'FIELD_TYPE': 1,
    'FORMULA': '$id',
    'INPUT': layer_A,
    'OUTPUT': parameters['LineID']
}
outputs['AddID'] = processing.run('native:fieldcalculator', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True) #2

layer_B = QgsVectorLayer(outputs['AddID']['OUTPUT'], 'layer_B')
renderer = layer_B.renderer()

symbol = QgsLineSymbol.createSimple({'line_color': '191,191,191,255', 'line_width': '0.20', 'line_style': 'dash'})
layer_B.renderer().setSymbol(symbol)
layer_B.triggerRepaint() # show the change
iface.layerTreeView().refreshLayerSymbology(layer_B.id()) # I want these changes to be effected in the output displayed.

results['LineID'] = layer_B

return results
```

When I run the routine above, I get this error message: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'setSymbol'. What can I do differently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The recommended way to do this is via the [QgsProcessingLayerPostProcessorInterface](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsProcessingLayerPostProcessorInterface.html) class. There are a few reasons for this. The first is that QGIS Processing Algorithms are run by default in a background thread. Therefore it is not thread-safe to interact with the canvas or interface from inside the `processAlgorithm()` method. While it is possible to re-implement the `flags()` method and return the `FlagNoThreading` flag, using a post-processor class makes sense because for an algorithm output, a proper destination parameter such as a `QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink` should be used. This gives the user the option to save to a temporary layer or a file location and also adds the checkbox to 'Open output file after running algorithm', and this can be handled cleanly by checking if `context.willLoadLayerOnCompletion()`, then accessing the `context.layerToLoadOnCompletionDetails()` and setting the post processor to the returned `QgsProcessingContext::LayerDetails` object.

Below is an example script which should show you how to do this. You can test it by adding it to the Processing toolbox, and adapting for your needs.

```py
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QCoreApplication
from qgis.core import (QgsProcessing,
                        QgsProcessingAlgorithm,
                        QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource,
                        QgsProcessingParameterExtent,
                        QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink,
                        QgsProcessingMultiStepFeedback,
                        QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem,
                        QgsProcessingLayerPostProcessorInterface,
                        QgsVectorLayer,
                        QgsLineSymbol)
import processing
                       
class ExAlgo(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):
    
    INPUT_LINES = 'INPUT_LINES'
    GRID_EXTENT = 'GRID_EXTENT'
    OUTPUT_GRID = 'OUTPUT_GRID'
    OUTPUT_LINES = 'OUTPUT_LINES'
 
    post_processors = {}
 
    def name(self):
        return "exalgo"
     
    def tr(self, text):
        return QCoreApplication.translate("exalgo", text)
         
    def displayName(self):
        return self.tr("Example script")
 
    def group(self):
        return self.tr("Examples")
 
    def groupId(self):
        return "examples"
 
    def shortHelpString(self):
        return self.tr("Example script which styles an output layers")
 
    def helpUrl(self):
        return "https://qgis.org"
         
    def createInstance(self):
        return ExAlgo()
        
    def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource(
            self.INPUT_LINES,
            self.tr("Input line layer"),
            [QgsProcessing.TypeVectorLine]))
            
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterExtent(
            self.GRID_EXTENT,
            self.tr("Line grid extent")
            ))
            
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink(
            self.OUTPUT_GRID,
            self.tr("Output line grid"),
            QgsProcessing.TypeVectorAnyGeometry))
    
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink(
            self.OUTPUT_LINES,
            self.tr("Output line layer"),
            QgsProcessing.TypeVectorAnyGeometry))

    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, model_feedback):
        feedback = QgsProcessingMultiStepFeedback(3, model_feedback)
        results = {}
        outputs = {}
        
        # Create line grid
        grid_params = {'TYPE':1,
                        'EXTENT':parameters[self.GRID_EXTENT],
                        'HSPACING':10000,
                        'VSPACING':10000,
                        'HOVERLAY':0,
                        'VOVERLAY':0,
                        'CRS':QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:3857'),# Never use 3857 for accurate distance measurement IRL!
                        'OUTPUT':parameters[self.OUTPUT_GRID]}
                        
        feedback.setCurrentStep(1)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}
            
        outputs['line_grid'] = processing.run("native:creategrid", grid_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)
        results['line_grid'] = outputs['line_grid']['OUTPUT']
                    
        # Fix Line Geometries
        fix_geom_params = {'INPUT':parameters[self.INPUT_LINES], 'OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'}
        
        feedback.setCurrentStep(2)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}
        
        outputs['fixed_geometries'] = processing.run('native:fixgeometries', fix_geom_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True) #1
        results['fixed_geometries'] = outputs['fixed_geometries']['OUTPUT']
            
        # Using Field calculator to Add an ID
        fld_calc_params = {
            'INPUT': results['fixed_geometries'],
            'FIELD_LENGTH': 10,
            'FIELD_NAME': 'ID',
            'FIELD_PRECISION': 0,
            'FIELD_TYPE': 1,
            'FORMULA': '$id',
            'OUTPUT': parameters[self.OUTPUT_LINES]
        }
        
        feedback.setCurrentStep(3)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}
                
        outputs['add_id'] = processing.run('native:fieldcalculator', fld_calc_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True) #2
        results['add_id'] = outputs['add_id']['OUTPUT']
        
        for lyr_id in results.values():
            if context.willLoadLayerOnCompletion(lyr_id):
                self.post_processors[lyr_id] = LayerPostProcessor.create()
                context.layerToLoadOnCompletionDetails(lyr_id).setPostProcessor(self.post_processors[lyr_id])

        return results
    

class LayerPostProcessor(QgsProcessingLayerPostProcessorInterface):

    instance = None

    def postProcessLayer(self, layer, context, feedback):
        print(layer.name())
        if not isinstance(layer, QgsVectorLayer):
            return
        renderer = layer.renderer().clone()
        symbol = QgsLineSymbol.createSimple({'line_color': '191,191,191,255', 'line_width': '0.20', 'line_style': 'dash'})
        renderer.setSymbol(symbol)
        layer.setRenderer(renderer)

    @staticmethod
    def create() -> 'LayerPostProcessor':
        LayerPostProcessor.instance = LayerPostProcessor()
        return LayerPostProcessor.instance
```

Result:

[image]

Acknowledgements:

I originally got the post processor example from a GitHub gist of QGIS core developer, Nyall Dawson. However this has now been deleted so I cannot provide a link.

The processing script template is adapted from [here](https://anitagraser.com/2018/03/25/processing-script-template-for-qgis3/).

Comment: Thank you so much @Ben W. I applied it to my plugin and it worked very well. Thanks :).