# Accessing processing.run() output layer in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis

The output of processing.run() in QGIS3 seems to be a dictionary where the `'OUTPUT'` variable is a string. I am trying to access the features of the resulting layer of the following code in PyQGIS:

```
layer2_exploded = processing.run("native:explodelines", {
    'INPUT':layer1_line,
    'OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'
}, is_child_algorithm=True, context=context, feedback=feedback)['OUTPUT']
```

If I try `layer2_exploded.getFeatures()` I get the error that `'str' object has no attribute 'getFeatures'`, and if I remove the `['OUTPUT']` at the end of the code block I get `'dict' object has no attribute 'getFeatures'`. So how do I access the layer, to be used with e.g. getFeatures?

Comment: If you put `is_child_algorithm=False`, then it shall work

Comment: @Taras, I tried that now, but it didn't work. Still getting 'str' object has no attribute 'getFeatures' error.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Regarding the question: "do I need to use `is_child_algorithm=True`?", you need to use it if the algorithm you are running is being run as a child or sub-algorithm, if you like, inside the `processAlgorithm()` method of a class which extends the `QgsProcessingAlgorithm` class. Based on your comments, I believe this is what you are doing here, however this fairly important detail is missing from your question.

Because, in the Python console you can simply do something like:

```py
layer2_exploded = processing.run("native:explodelines",
                                {'INPUT':iface.activeLayer(),
                                'OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'})['OUTPUT']
```

And the return value of the `run()` call stored in the `layer2_exploded` variable will be a `QgsVectorLayer` object; because `is_child_algorithm` defaults to `False`, so ownership of the result layer is transferred from the processing context back to the caller.

However, when you are doing `processing.run()` calls to child algorithms as steps in the `processAlgorithm()` method of a `QgsProcessingAlgorithm` subclass, you must set the `is_child_algorithm` argument to `True`. This will mean that ownership remains with the context and that return value of the `run()` call will be a map layer id string reference. This why you are getting the error you describe.

If you need to work with a `QgsVectorLayer` object, you can use the method [QgsProcessingContext.getMapLayer()](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsProcessingContext.html#a5c4bd1a2505981001fe28d42e9ff3238) method which returns a `QgsMapLayer` object from a layer id string. You can see in the [source code](https://api.qgis.org/api/qgsprocessingcontext_8cpp_source.html#l00122), that this method calls the [QgsProcessingUtils.mapLayerFromString()](https://api.qgis.org/api/3.4/classQgsProcessingUtils.html#a4ae097e24153b9ebaa503939c956b1ca) method, which you could also use.

So an example for your case is:

```py
layer2_exploded_id = processing.run("native:explodelines",
                                {'INPUT':layer1_line,
                                'OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'},
                                context=context,
                                feedback=feedback,
                                is_child_algorithm=True)['OUTPUT']

vlyr = context.getMapLayer(layer2_exploded_id)# QgsVectorLayer object
```

Here is a trivial but complete, minimal example of a `QgsProcessingAlgorithm` making use of this method. Here we check the feature count of the vector layer returned by `context.getMapLayer()`, and if it is over 1000, we create a feature request limited to 1000 features, and add those to the output feature sink.

```py
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QCoreApplication, QVariant

from qgis.core import (QgsFeatureSink, QgsFeatureRequest,
        QgsProcessing, QgsProcessingAlgorithm, QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource,
        QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink, QgsProcessingUtils)
        
import processing

class ExAlgo(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):
    INPUT = 'INPUT'
    OUTPUT = 'OUTPUT'

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def name(self):
        return "exalgo"
    
    def tr(self, text):
        return QCoreApplication.translate("exalgo", text)
        
    def displayName(self):
        return self.tr("Example script")

    def group(self):
        return self.tr("Examples")

    def groupId(self):
        return "examples"

    def shortHelpString(self):
        return self.tr("Example script without logic")

    def helpUrl(self):
        return "https://qgis.org"
        
    def createInstance(self):
        return type(self)()
  
    def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource(
            self.INPUT,
            self.tr("Input layer"),
            [QgsProcessing.TypeVectorLine]))

        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink(
            self.OUTPUT,
            self.tr("Output layer"),
            QgsProcessing.TypeVectorLine))

    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):
        source = self.parameterAsSource(parameters, self.INPUT, context)
        
        layer1_line = source.materialize(QgsFeatureRequest(), feedback=feedback)

        (sink, dest_id) = self.parameterAsSink(parameters, self.OUTPUT, context,
                                               source.fields(), source.wkbType(), source.sourceCrs())

        layer2_exploded_id = processing.run("native:explodelines",
                                        {'INPUT':layer1_line,
                                        'OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'},
                                        context=context,
                                        feedback=feedback,
                                        is_child_algorithm=True)['OUTPUT']
        
        vlyr = context.getMapLayer(layer2_exploded_id)
        
        feat_request = QgsFeatureRequest()
        
        if vlyr.featureCount() > 1000:
            feat_request.setLimit(1000)
            
        for f in vlyr.getFeatures(feat_request):
            sink.addFeature(f, QgsFeatureSink.FastInsert)

        return {'self.OUTPUT': dest_id}
```

The QGIS processing framework is a wonderful and versatile tool, but there is a fairly steep learning curve with it and many gotchas. For example, QGIS Processing Algorithms are run by default in a background thread. Therefore it is not thread-safe to interact with the canvas or interface from inside the `processAlgorithm()` method. While it is possible to re-implement the `flags()` method and return the `FlagNoThreading` flag, I don't recommend doing anything non thread safe with your `QgsVectorLayer` object from inside the `processAlgorithm()` method. While `getFeatures()` is fine, don't do anything which interacts with the interface such as applying a style to the layer object etc. For post processing of any output layers which will be loaded on completion, there is the  [QgsProcessingLayerPostProcessorInterface](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsProcessingLayerPostProcessorInterface.html) class. You can see an example [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/448603/change-the-symbology-of-a-vector-output-layer-that-is-returned-from-a-processing/448613#448613).

There is also the [postProcessAlgorithm](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsProcessingAlgorithm.html#a8cfe93b703357bb38247424af323a951) method, which *should* be called from the main thread and can be re-implemented to perform any thread-sensitive cleanup tasks.

I hope all this information does not confuse you too much. Most of this is probably not relevant to you at the moment. I am just trying to make you aware of things to watch out for if you get more in depth with writing processing scripts.

Comment: Thank you very much for this in-depth answer! Solved the problem, and makes it much easier to remember when you start to understand the reasons for the different approaches. +1!

Comment: Thanks @ben-w! Couldn't figure out why the output of `Extract by Location` is a string, but I could get the layer by using [QgsProcessingUtils.mapLayerFromString()](https://api.qgis.org/api/3.4/classQgsProcessingUtils.html#a4ae097e24153b9ebaa503939c956b1ca) with `context=context`

Answer (score 0):

Do you need "is_child_algorithm=True, context=context, feedback=feedback"?

You can use the output of a processing algorithm with:

```
algo = "native:explodelines"
params = {'INPUT':iface.activeLayer(),'OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'}

output = processing.run(algo, params)['OUTPUT']
print(output.featureCount())
```

Comment: I'm not really sure whether I need them, I'm a beginner just trying to follow the guidelines that I read about. I have lots of other processing.run() blocks in a sequence, and therefore I should set it to True, according to what I read [here](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing/scripts.html).
Although I tried to change only this code block to `is_child_algorithm=True` and the whole thing crashed when I ran it. How do I know when to use True and when to use False for this parameter? What effect does it have?