# 'Could not load source layer for INPUT: invalid value' error in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-processing, error, input

I'm trying to implement a processing plugins in QGIS 3.28.9, but when I hit <kbd>Run</kbd>, it gives me a message that my polygon layer is not a polygon layer, but, it is a polygon, in fact. Can someone help to fix this problem?

[image: plugin error]

[image: my polygon test layer]

code:

```py
def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):
    
    source = self.parameterAsSource(parameters, self.INPUT, context)

    if source is None or source.wkbType() != QgsWkbTypes.PolygonGeometry:
        raise QgsProcessingException('Invalid input source. Expected a polygon layer.') 


    feedback.setProgressText('Converting polygons to lines...')
    converted_lines = processing.run("qgis:polygonstolines", {
        'INPUT': source,
        'OUTPUT': 'memory:'  # Convert to a temporary memory layer
    })['OUTPUT']

    # Get the output sink
    sink = self.parameterAsSink(parameters, self.OUTUPUT, context,
                                converted_lines.fields(), QgsProcessing.TypeVectorLine)
    if sink is None:
        raise QgsProcessingException('Invalid output sink')
    
    # Add converted lines to the output sink
    sink.addFeatures(converted_lines.getFeatures())
    
    return {self.OUTPUT: sink}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your layer has a `MultiPolygon` geometry type. Therefore, the `source.wkbType()` test will return [`WkbType.MultiPolygon`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgis.html#adf94495b88fbb3c5df092267ccc94509) which is why the processing exception is being raised.

Change your conditional statement to:

```py
if source is None or QgsWkbTypes.geometryType(source.wkbType()) != QgsWkbTypes.PolygonGeometry:
    raise QgsProcessingException('Invalid input source. Expected a polygon layer.')
```

I assume that you are already passing a list of types to the `QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource` constructor so that the input layer dropdown box is filtered e.g.

```py
def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
    self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource(
        self.INPUT,
        self.tr("Input polygon layer"),
        [QgsProcessing.TypeVectorPolygon]))
```

But, since it is still possible to select a different input type when using browse or select file...

[image]

...a check of the input geometry type is indeed prudent.

However, I suggest that an alternative (and perhaps better practice) way to run the input check is to re-implement and override the [`checkParameterValues`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsProcessingAlgorithm.html#ae3991f84be1b939144df415bec29d3fd) method of the `QgsProcessingAlgorithm` class and do the check there.

```py
def checkParameterValues(self, parameters, context):
    source = self.parameterAsSource(parameters, self.INPUT, context)

    if source is None or QgsWkbTypes.geometryType(source.wkbType()) != QgsWkbTypes.PolygonGeometry:
        return False, self.tr('Invalid input source. Expected a polygon layer.')

    return super().checkParameterValues(parameters, context)
```

Here, we can implement our own logic and return `False` and a helpful message string if the check fails.

Following this recommendation given in the docs:

> Overridden implementations should also check this base class
> implementation.

we can use [super()](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_super.asp) which returns an object which represents the base or parent class of a subclass (in this case `QgsProcessingAlgorithm`) and call the default implementation of `checkParameterValues()`, returning the result- as in [this example](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/94d2f8555df2e4125f53109e346508e8ba382727/python/plugins/processing/algs/qgis/TilesXYZ.py#L354).

Now, if you try to run the algorithm with a non-polygon layer input, you will see this:

[image]

Edit: There are a few other issues with your code. You have not passed `is_child_algorithm=True` to your `processing.run()` call. This is required since the "native:polygonstolines" alg is being run inside a parent algorithm.

As for the persistent error you were getting, I found that to get the child algorithm to accept the parent input, I had to call the `materialize()` method on the `QgsProcessingFeatureSource` object to return an in memory copy as a `QgsVectorLayer` object.

Below is a complete working example. By the way, I guess that you will be adding some more processing steps because, as it is, this whole script is just a wrapper around an existing algorithm. If you add more steps you may want to use `QgsProcessingMultiStepFeedback`. You can see an example in my recent answer [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/464906/pyqgis-3-22-custom-processing-script-problem-inputting-raster-and-processing-zo/465090#465090).

```py
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QCoreApplication, QVariant
from qgis.core import (QgsProcessing, QgsProcessingAlgorithm,
                        QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource,
                        QgsProcessingParameterVectorDestination,
                        QgsWkbTypes, QgsFeatureRequest)
                        
import processing
                       
class ConvertPolygons(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):
    INPUT = 'INPUT'
    OUTPUT = 'OUTPUT'
 
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
 
    def name(self):
        return "exportarpolygonos"
     
    def tr(self, text):
        return QCoreApplication.translate("exportarpolygonos", text)
         
    def displayName(self):
        return self.tr("Exportar Polygonos")
 
    def group(self):
        return self.tr("Examples")
 
    def groupId(self):
        return "examples"
 
    def shortHelpString(self):
        return self.tr("Exportar Polygonos")
 
    def helpUrl(self):
        return "https://qgis.org"
         
    def createInstance(self):
        return type(self)()
        
    def checkParameterValues(self, parameters, context):
        source = self.parameterAsSource(parameters, self.INPUT, context)

        if source is None or QgsWkbTypes.geometryType(source.wkbType()) != QgsWkbTypes.PolygonGeometry:
            return False, self.tr('Invalid input source. Expected a polygon layer.')

        return super().checkParameterValues(parameters, context)
   
    def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource(
            self.INPUT,
            self.tr("Input polygons"),
            [QgsProcessing.TypeVectorPolygon]))
            
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterVectorDestination(
                self.OUTPUT,
                self.tr('Output lines')))
 
    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):
        source = self.parameterAsSource(parameters, self.INPUT, context).materialize(QgsFeatureRequest())
        
        results = {}
        outputs = {}
        
        feedback.setProgressText('Converting polygons to lines...')
        
        outputs['converted_lines'] = processing.run("native:polygonstolines",
                        {'INPUT':source, 'OUTPUT':parameters['OUTPUT']},
                        context=context,
                        feedback=feedback,
                        is_child_algorithm=True)
        
        results['OUTPUT'] = outputs['converted_lines']['OUTPUT']
        
        return results
```

Comment: Great answer! Can you please explain a bit what the `super()` actually does in this statement `super().getParameterValues(parameters, context)` ?

Comment: Hi @Taras! I have expanded my answer a bit :-)

Comment: Still not working. Now Qgis raised the same error, 'Unable to execute algorithm
Could not load source layer for INPUT: invalid value'

Comment: @Luiz Paulo Zampronio, see my updated answer with a full working example.